# How to create 3d tag sphere UI for android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

In this layout image rotate on mouse touch and also highlight front name in big font and on click it show next Activity.

How do I create this on Android?

[image]

Comment: use a SurfaceView, draw the different images on the surfaceview while attaching click events to them, attach a GestureListener to the activity which will tell the surfaceview to rotate the images it contains

Comment: You can make this type of UI by using surface view and using of GestureListener in your activity.

Comment: Use a web view and the scripting to do this

Comment: There is an example at https://sites.google.com/site/tagindemo/TagCloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible implementation is as follows:

- Create an invisible sphere. The sphere's vertices are calculated as positions for the labels but not drawn. You can find the sphere algorithm in several answers in SO, e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811082/spinning-globe-in-opengl-es.).
- Attach the labels to different points on the sphere, each label always facing the camera.
- Rotate the sphere based on user drag action
- Fade the words based on z value.
- Tapping a label will rotate the invisible sphere to bring the label to the front.

This can be implemented either in a SurfaceView, or GLSurfaceView with OpenGL. If you use SurfaceView you probably need to keep the number of labels/vertices low to make it run smoothly.

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/tagindemo/TagCloud) is a tutorial on how to create a rotating tag sphere for Android.